# MDC is not Effective other than Filter in Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2, mdc

I am using MDC for logging sessionId for each request to my spring boot app.
I am using log4j2 for logging.
When I am putting any key in Filter for example following is my Filter class.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.jboss.logging.MDC;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

    @Component
    public class MDCFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            MDC.put("sessionId", "12345");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }
```

When I try to put "sessionId" key in my controller. It is not taking my controller value in logs.

For example : I am adding in my controller as:

```
MDC.put("sessionId", "ABC");
```

But in my logs still printing **"12345"**.

Why MDC is not effective other than Filter?

Answer (score 0):

Please use following MDC class:

```
org.jboss.logging.MDC
```